# Error with UILabel line breaks on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, label, uilabel

I have one problem. In my app I am using UILabels and Autolayout created by Objective-c code. I set number of lines to 0.

When I have label text is on letter(character) longer, than label width.
When I have set line breaks mode to word wrap, it is add dots to end.
When I have set line breaks mode to other, it is add new line with last word. But didn't resize label.

If text is longer, is is working correctly.

I can't find reason, what is causing this.
Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Provide some cod with setting constraints to UILabel?